# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency when passing empty array as second argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following `useEffect` hook in my functional component that I only want to use once (when the component mounts) in order to load some data from an API:

```
const Gear = () => {
  const [weaponOptions, setWeaponOptions] = useState([
    {
      key: "0",
      label: "",
      value: "null"
    }
  ]);
  const [weapon, setWeapon] = useState("null");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Gear.tsx useEffect");

    const fetchWeaponsOptions = async (): Promise<void> => {
      const weaponsData = await getWeapons();
      const newWeaponOptions: DropdownOptionType[] = [
        ...weaponOptions,
        ...weaponsData.map(({ id, name }) => {
          return {
            key: id,
            label: name,
            value: id
          };
        })
      ];
      setWeaponOptions(newWeaponOptions);
    };

    fetchWeaponsOptions();
  }, []);

  // TODO add weapon dropdown on change, selected weapon state
  const handleWeaponChange = ({ value }: DropdownOptionType): void => {
    setWeapon(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Gear:</h2>
      <Dropdown
        defaultValue={weapon}
        label="Weapon"
        name="weapon"
        options={weaponOptions}
        onChange={handleWeaponChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

A [React documentation note](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) states that this is valid practice when you only want the effect to run on mount an unmount:

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
>   unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
>   tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
>   or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
>   case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
>   works.

But I am getting the following create-react-app linter warning:

`35:6  warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'weaponOptions'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

The useEffect triggers if the `weaponOptions` array changes if I pass it as a dependency, resulting in an endless loop because the hook itself changes the weaponOptions state. The same thing happens if I omit the empty array argument.

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: It will, please show us where does `weaponOptions` comes from

Comment: @DennisVash sry, added the whole functional component code to the initial question to make things clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I only want to use once (when the component mounts) in order to load some data from an API

Therefore according to your logic, you don't need to depend on the component's state:

```
const INITIAL = [
  {
    key: '0',
    label: '',
    value: 'null'
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [weaponOptions, setWeaponOptions] = useState(INITIAL);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWeaponsOptions = async () => {
      const weaponsData = await getWeapons();
      const weaponsOptions = [
        ...INITIAL, // No state dependency needed
        ...weaponsData.map(({ id, name }) => {
          return {
            key: id,
            label: name,
            value: id
          };
        })
      ];
      setWeaponOptions(weaponsOptions);
    };

  }, []);

  return <></>;
};
```

But, it is common when you want to use a `useEffect` once, and it depends on a state, to use a boolean reference like so:

```
const App = () => {
  const [weaponOptions, setWeaponOptions] = useState(INITIAL);

  const isFirstFetch = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWeaponsOptions = async () => {...}

    if (isFirstFetch.current) {
      fetchWeaponsOptions();
      isFirstFetch.current = false;
    }
  }, [weaponOptions]);

  return <></>;
};
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense :). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As you can see that is not an error but a warning. **React** is telling you that you are using `weaponOptions` inside `useEffect` but you didn't pass it as a dependency. Again, that is just a warning, you don't have to do it.